# list index out of range al procesar un fichero csv

Tags: python, csv

Esta es la línea completa del fichero CSV donde da el error:

```
21890;BH Telecom (PTT BiH, GSMBIH);Bosnia and Herzegovina
```

Si mando a imprimir la variable `split` me lo pone hasta aquí:

```
21890;BH Telecom (PTT BiH
```

Donde empieza la coma (**,**). Este es mi código:

```
for row in valores_bajo_cabecera:
        cont += 1

        split = row[0].split(';')
        imsi = split[0]
        operador = split[1]
        paiss = split[2]
```

Comment: Hola Coloma, sin ver el fichero (o alguna línea de ejemplo) es muy difícil saber qué sucede. Es más, te recomiendo que trates de aislar el problema viendo en qué línea se produce el error y eliminando todo el código que no tiene nada que ver con el error (como la parte en la que usas `Operador`, que no aporta nada a la pregunta). Un saludo y suerte.

Comment: Ampliando lo que dice @astrojuanlu, no está clara la relación con [tag:django]. Haz una simple prueba únicamente del código que te falle, sin nada más.

Comment: Gracias, voy arreglar esos problemas !! es q soy nuevo en esta pagina !!

Comment: Hola, ¿como estás creando el reader del CSV? Es mejor si muestras tu código completo.

Comment: el fichero era un excel q lo converti a csv, separado por punto y como(;)

Comment: ¿No estás usando el módulo CSV de Python con `import csv`?

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es que uses el módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) de Python. Imaginando que tienes un archivo CSV como el siguiente:

```
CAMPO1;CAMPO2;CAMPO3
21890;BH Telecom (PTT BiH, GSMBIH);Bosnia and Herzegovina
21891;BH Telecom (PTT BiH, GSMBIH);Germany
21892;BH Entel;China
```

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
import csv


archivo = open('archivo.csv')
reader = csv.reader(archivo, delimiter=';')
cabecera = reader.next()
print 'Cabecera:', cabecera

for fila in reader:
    print '-' * 50
    imsi = fila[0]
    operador = fila[1]
    pais = fila[2]
    print 'IMSI:', imsi
    print 'Operador:',  operador
    print 'Pais:', pais
print '-' * 50
```

El resultado del código anterior es:

```
Cabecera: ['CAMPO1', 'CAMPO2', 'CAMPO3']
--------------------------------------------------
IMSI: 21890
Operador: BH Telecom (PTT BiH, GSMBIH)
Pais: Bosnia and Herzegovina
--------------------------------------------------
IMSI: 21891
Operador: BH Telecom (PTT BiH, GSMBIH)
Pais: Germany
--------------------------------------------------
IMSI: 21892
Operador: BH Entel
Pais: China
--------------------------------------------------
```

Observa que el `reader` le estoy pasando el delimitador `;` (por defecto es la coma) y que estoy deshaciendome de la cabecera antes de comenzar el bucle con esta línea:

```
cabecera = reader.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta imprimir la variable row[0] antes de asignarla a la variable split y comprueba que muestra la linea completa "21890;BH Telecom (PTT BiH, GSMBIH);Bosnia and Herzegovina" por que a lo mejor al sacar el valor de row solo te coje la parte antes de la coma:

for row in valores_bajo_cabecera:
        cont += 1

```
    print(row[0])
    split = row[0].split(';')
    imsi = split[0]
    operador = split[1]
    paiss = split[2]
```